# ArangoDB Java Driver: put multiple parameters in transaction

Tags: java, arangodb

I need to put multiple parameters in transaction in JAVA drived for ArangoDB;

It works with single parameter:

```
public String save(User user) throws ArangoDBException {

    TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions().params(user).writeCollections(collectionName);
    String action = "function (params) { "
            + "var db = require('internal').db; "
            + "var doc = params;"
            + "db.users.save(doc);"
            + "}";

    return db.transaction(action, String.class, options);
}
```

But if I need to pass multiple parameters, then I'm stuck. Tried to pass map, arraylist or array, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public void save(User user, User user2) throws ArangoDBException {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new MapBuilder()
            .put("user", user)
            .put("user2" user2)
            .get();


    TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions().params(parameters).writeCollections(collectionName);
    String action = "function (params) { "
            + "var db = require('internal').db; "
            + "var doc = params['user'];"
            + "var doc2 = params['user2'];"
            + "db.users.save(doc);"
            + "db.users.save(doc2);"
            + "}";

    db.transaction(action, String.class, options);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need of your workaround is not necessary any more. The missing automatic serialization of map/list/array within `TransactionOptions` was a bug in the java-driver which is fixed with version 4.1.5

Answer (score 0):

Had to serialize the map:

```
TransactionOptions().params(db.util().serialize(params)).writeCollections(collectionName, "users2");
```